# Dropbox doesn't download all folders

Tags: dropbox

I am using Dropbox with a group of students. Some of us don't see all folders via the app.

If you go online they are all there. It oesn't seem to sync. We have tried uninstalling/installing, going through all preferences.

Is this issue known to anyone? We hope someone can help us out.

Comment: Which opersating system(s) is/are involved? Have you also tried removing [the application settings](https://www.dropbox.com/help/41/en) as outlined here? See also: [What do I do if Dropbox is stuck syncing, won't launch, or reports an error? - Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/help/72/en)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, in appdata it won't let me delete it: error says acces denied. no process running in the background and dropbox is uninstalled. i'll try a reboot first. and will let you know what happens. thank you sofar!

Comment: Did all the steps as suggested in the link but no such luck.it just doesn't sync two folders at all. it doesn't download the folder so it's not that the folder is there with nothing in it. it's missing completely. quite frustrating. more tips are welcome!

Comment: I had a stroke of genius. my mac did show all files, just not the windows pcs. the folder was called "integrated assignment" WITH the "" ... now the mac think this is fine, but windows doesn't allow it. removing the "" did fix it instantly. hooray!!!!

Comment: That's great! You can come back in a few hours (7 or so) and post this as a real answer below your question. That way, others might benefit from seeing the solution where it really belongs :)

Comment: @Annemarie: Could you please copy-paste your last comment into an answer (answering your oewn question) and accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To figure out what files will have problems syncing, go to the Dropbox "bad files" page: https://www.dropbox.com/bad_files_check